# What is the result supposed to be of the command "cut -f 1,2 list.txt"?

Tags: bash

I tried using the command `cut -f 1,2 list.txt` on a list but for some reason the output of the list it gives me remains the same, I'm not seeing any difference. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: What separates the list? ... might have to change the delimiter `-d` too. https://shapeshed.com/unix-cut/

Comment: @PaulT.  Just spaces separating everything, I've also tried it with commas but no difference. The thing that's weird about it is that this command is from a schoolwork question and I have to choose the answer of what it does but I can't figure it out since for me it does nothing. Not sure if the command has a mistake on it or what but it's what he put on there.

Comment: It is supposed to break up each line into fields by _TAB_ characters, and output the first and second field from each line. If you don't see any difference, it means that the lines don't contain at least two TAB-characters.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to read `cut`'s documentation on your machine by typing `man cut` or `info cut` (on Gnu Linux systems). If neither of those work, you can find the same documentation on-line, but you will really find it more convenient to have command-tool documentation at your fingertips:

- [FreeBSD / MacOS version](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?cut)
- [GNU/Linux version](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html)
- [GNU Coreutils documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/cut-invocation.html#cut-invocation)
- [Posix standard, via the Linux documentation project](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1p.html)

These are all quite similar, since the Posix standard applies; some implementations have additional features, but they should all be based on the Posix standard, which includes the following relevant command-line options:

> -d delim
>
> Set the field delimiter to the character `delim`.  The default is the <tab>.
>
> -f list
>
> Cut based on a list of fields, assumed to be separated in the file by a delimiter character (see **-d**). Each selected field shall be output. Output fields shall be separated by a single occurrence of the field delimiter character. Lines with no field delimiters shall be passed through intact, unless **-s** is specified. It shall not be an error to select fields not present in the input line.

There's a lot more, but that should be enough to answer your question. `cut -f1,2` prints fields 1 and 2, where fields are separated by a <tab> character. If there is no tab character in a line (probably the case in your sample inputs), it is passed through intact.